# Keep auxiliary TeX files when rendering a rmarkdown document

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

I am rendering two documents, that cross-reference items in each other. For that I am using the LaTeX package `zref`.

To make `zref` work, it needs the `*.aux` file of the documents which are created when calling `pdflatex`.

Unfortunately, using RStudio and its basic approach to render the document (the knit button, Cmd+Shift+K or `rmarkdown::render()`) these files will be deleted after the compilation was successful.

Unchecking the global option *Tools -> Global Options -> Sweave -> Clean auxiliary output after compile* does not help.

I know of two options to go around this:

1. Manually compile the tex file after the pdf was rendered.
2. Write a makefile that does that.

But is there another option I am not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`rmarkdown::render()` eventually calls `tinytex::latexmk()` to compile the intermediate `.tex` to `.pdf`. To preserve auxiliary files, you need `tinytex::latexmk(..., clean = FALSE)`. One way to set `clean = FALSE` is through the global option `options(tinytex.clean = FALSE)`. You can set this in either your `.Rprofile` or a code chunk of your Rmd document.

The RStudio option you mentioned is only for Sweave documents (`.Rnw`).

Comment: Man I cannot wrap my head around that it works. Thanks! With all the stuff goin on around my RMD (`pandoc`, `rmarkdown`, `knitr`, `tinytex`) I sometimes do not see the obvious.

Comment: Would the same approach work for the manual that is build using devtools? I cannot find the tex files D: